# Типизация объекта класса, который реализует два абстрактных класса

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп, интерфейс, типы-данных

Есть два абстрактных класса `IWalker`, и `ITalker`, и есть класс который реализует и наследует эти два абстрактных класса. Однако я не знаю **как сделать [type hint](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/)** для класса, который **реализует сразу несколько абстрактных классов**. Будьте столь любезны, подскажите любителю типизации в динамически типизированном языке.

Код:

```py
import abc
import random
from typing import List


class IWalker(abc.ABC):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def walk(self):
        ...


class ITalker(abc.ABC):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def talk(self):
        ...


class Bactria(IWalker):
    def walk(self):
        print("Бактерия ходит")


class Virus(IWalker):
    def walk(self):
        print("Вирус двигается")


class Penguin(IWalker, ITalker):
    def talk(self):
        print("Linux")

    def walk(self):
        print("Пингвин скатывается по пузу: фью-ю-ю")


class Elephant(IWalker, ITalker):
    def walk(self):
        print("Слон ходит: Топ, топ, топ")

    def talk(self):
        print("Слон говорит: ру-у-у")


def process_talkers_and_walkers(talker_and_walker: ...):
    talker_and_walker.walk()
    talker_and_walker.talk()


def without_typing_code():
    talkers_and_walkers: List[...] = [Penguin, Elephant]
    random_talker_and_walker: ... = random.choice(talkers_and_walkers)()
    process_talkers_and_walkers(random_talker_and_walker)
```

Comment: Смотря какая цель, какую проблему/задачу вы пытаетесь данной аннотацией. Если у вас одиночный объект, то вообще без разницы, просто Elephant поставьте (хотя это избыточно). Или интерфейс, методы которого вы будете вызывать от объекта. Если у вас был бы например список IWalker'ов, то стоило бы поставить `List[IWalker]`, т.е. общий интерфейс. Можно еще как вариант описать общий тип, который реализует оба интерфейса.

Comment: Аннотацией я явно объявляю IDE тип объекта. В реальности у меня >3 "слонов", и >9 "бактерий".

Comment: Ну описывайте их слонами и бактериями (конкретными классами).

Comment: `elephant: Elephant = Elephant()`

Comment: Изменил код в надежде более детально показать суть своей проблемы. Если я буду описывать конкретными классами, то это будет слишком большой `Union`. Мне необходимо обозначить тип у объекта класса, который реализует `IWalker`-а, и `ITalker`-а. Собственно это я и выделил жирным, в своём вопросе: "как сделать type hint для класса, реализующего сразу несколько абстрактных классов"

Comment: Нормально и красиво то что вы хотите - никак. Можно через `Union[IWalker, ITalker]`, но при обращении к объекту придется проверять, что объект реализует нужный интерфейс. Проще сделать, чтобы все классы реализовали оба интерфейса, а те кто не могут говорить (например) при вызове `talk` ничего бы не делали, или кидали ошибку `NotImplementedError`.